# Sum Of Subsets Program

Tags: c++, subset-sum

I am new to C++ and am writing a sum of subsets program that takes in a user defined set of numbers, the first number of which is considered to be the total. I have tried using DDD to debug this program, however I continue to get an out-of-bounds error.  I cannot seem to find out why this is happening.  Any clues?  Thanks.
Here is the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what(): vector::_M_range_check
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <iomanip>
#include <climits>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>

typedef unsigned int uint;
using namespace std;

//////// Function declerations //////////
void sum_of_subsets( uint index, 
                     uint weight, 
                     uint total, 
                     vector<bool> &include, 
                     vector<uint> &w,
                     uint W );

bool promising ( uint index, 
                 uint weight, 
                 uint W, 
                 vector<uint> w,
                 uint total );
```

.

```
/////////////// Main //////////////////
int main()
{
    //string sortingCode = "-as";
    vector<uint> w;             // vector of weights
    vector<bool> include;       
        uint W;                     // the total
    uint index = 0;
    uint weight = 0;            // the current weight of subsets
    uint total = 0;             // the superset total weight
    while( ! cin.eof() )
  {
    uint value;
    if( cin >> value && ! cin.eof() )
      w.push_back( value );
  }

    W = w.front();
    w.erase( w.begin() );
    // instantiate the include vector to false
    for( uint k = 0; k <= w.size(); k++ )
        include.push_back(0);
    // calculate the superset total
    for( uint k = 0; k <= w.size()-1; k++ )
        total += w.at(k);
    // calculate the sum of subsets accordig to CL argument
    sum_of_subsets( index, weight, total, include, w, W );

    // report success   
    return 0;
}
```

.

```
////////// Function Bodies ///////////
void sum_of_subsets( uint index, 
                     uint weight, 
                     uint total, 
                     vector<bool> &include, 
                     vector<uint> &w, 
                     uint W )
{    
    cout << "inside sumb_of_subsets" << endl;
    if( promising(index, weight, W, w, total) )
    {   
        cout << "promising is true, continue" << endl;
        if( weight == W )
        {   
            for( uint k = 0; k <= index; k++ )
            {
                if(include.at(k))
                    cout << w.at(k) << " ";;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            include.at(index + 1) = 1;
            cout << "index1 = " << index << endl;
            sum_of_subsets( index + 1, 
                            weight + w.at(index + 1 ), 
                            total - w.at(index + 1),
                            include, w, W ) ;
            include.at(index + 1) = 0;
            cout << "index2 = " << index << endl;
            sum_of_subsets( index + 1, 
                            weight, 
                            total - w.at(index + 1),
                            include, w, W );
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
bool promising ( uint index, 
                 uint weight, 
                 uint W, 
                 vector<uint> w,
                 uint total )
{    
    cout << "inside promising" << endl;
    cout << "W = " << W << endl;
    cout << "weight = " << weight << endl;
    return ( weight + total >= W )
         && ( (weight == W) || (weight + w.at(index+1) <= W));
}
```

Comment: "however I continue to get an out-of-bounds error" - Please share your error messages.

Comment: I edited my question above to include the error

Comment: On what line did ddd say this happened?

Comment: What input causes said error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what(): vector::_M_range_check
```

Suggests that your debug version of vector is throwing an exception, and nothing catches it. When this happens, the program immediately terminates without unwinding the stack, which makes debugging harder.

Change to this:

```
// calculate the sum of subsets accordig to CL argument
try
{
  sum_of_subsets( index, weight, total, include, w, W );
}
catch (...)
{
  cout << "put breakpoint here!" << endl;
}
```

Add a breakpoint in the catch, and check the backtrace to see what part of your code went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for that, however the for loop indices are not resulting in my problem.  I believe it has to do with the recursive call to sum_of_subsets, however I couldn't pinpoint where and why while debugging.

Comment: In ddd, what do you get when you type bt (or backtrace) after the crash?

Comment: @SeanHellebusch Pretty sure it's that you're going out of bounds.